# MySQL consolidate encoding of all tables

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL database as some of the tables in it are utf-8 encoded and some are not.
I would like to get all the table and data consolidate to be utf-8.

Is there a batch command to achieve so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name [COLLATE collation_name];
```

You can whip this into some procedure or batch script.